# Derivative of product with integral term

Tags: derivatives

I have a quesiton about the product rule. If I want to take the derivative of
\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dx} \left(a(x) \int\limits_{x_1}^{x_2} b(x) dx \right) 
\end{equation} 
do I have to use a product rule, i.e. $\frac{da(x)}{dx} \left(\int\limits_{x_1}^{x_2} b(x) dx \right) + a(x) b(x)$, or not?

Comment: Hint: consider changing the variable of integration to $y$.  How is the expression now different?

Comment: I think that the notation in the mathematical expression you wrote is confusing. You're trying to take the derivative of the function in parenthesis with respect to 'x', but the function inside the parenthesis has an 'x' in the function 'a(x)', but there is also another 'x' in the integral which is used as a 'dummy' variable for the integration and it doesn't make sense to take the derivative with respect to this variable.

Comment: The integral is not a function of $x$, it is a function of the constants $x_1$ and $x_2$ and is itself then constant. Even so the notation is ambiguous as Samuel points out. Although if it was a function of $x$, then yes the normal product rule would apply, and then you'd have to apply the Leibniz rule for integrals. Overall though this is a question for Math stackechange.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dx} \left(a(x) \int\limits_{x_1}^{x_2} b(x) dx \right) 
\end{equation}=$$

$$\frac{da(x)}{dx} \left(\int\limits_{x_1}^{x_2} b(x) dx \right) + a(x)\frac{d}{dx}\int\limits_{x_1}^{x_2} b(x) dx= $$

$$\frac{da(x)}{dx} \left(\int\limits_{x_1}^{x_2} b(x) dx \right)$$

Note that $$ \int\limits_{x_1}^{x_2} b(x) dx $$
is a constant.